# I am not getting .bashrc file on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk

I'm struggling a lot to install JDK in Ubuntu. I have these steps followed:

- Downloaded `jdk-8u73-linux-i586.tar.gz` and extracted the file.
- Placed `jdk1.8.0_73` in `/usr/lib/java`.
- Ran the scripts below:

  ```sh
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java" 1
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/javac" 1
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/javaws" 1
  ```

After this when I try to run the `java - version`, I got this:

```
$ java -version
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest try installing Oracle Java8 on your ubuntu by following these steps. Open the terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Once done, verify the installation

```
java -version
javac -version
```

Setting up the Java Environment

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. :)

What is the path in the default installer case? Actually, I am trying to install Hadoop single node cluster on my Ubantu VM.